# How to pass parameter from custom button & open a vf page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, url

I want to pass the Quote Id to the controller on click of a custom button & open the vf page called Select Product.
Currently i'm using this code:-
`apex/SelectProduct?id={!Quote.Id}`
I have kept the content source as URL.
But it is giving me following error:- URL No Longer Exists

Comment: Try add another backslash before 'apex' - `/apex/SelectProduct?id={!Quote.Id}`

Comment: I've posted it as an official answer, please accept it so we don't have open questions floating around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another backslash before 'apex' - `/apex/SelectProduct?id={!Quote.Id}`. Without that, the relative URL will be appended to the base host URL and it will create an invalid one.

For an example if you have `https://na13.salesforce.com` and you don't have the first backslash, it will create an URL like this : `https://na13.salesforce.comapex/SelectProduct?id={!Quote.Id}` instead of `https://na13.salesforce.com/apex/SelectProduct?id={!Quote.Id}`